# How do I discontinue federal voluntary witholding tax on my social security retirement?

Tags: taxes, deduction

I want to discontinue my voluntary federal tax withholding of $438.20 per month.  I retired on 8/31.19.  thanks in advance.

Comment: What country are you in? From what income is this money being withheld?

Comment: Typing '"social security" stop income tax withholding' into a search engine will return millions of hits, of which this was the first: https://www.ssa.gov/planners/taxwithold.html  (I'm assuming you're in the US, and the money's being withheld from monthly SS benefits.)